# bad bind variable in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, sequence

I am trying to create a trigger but somehow I'm getting error called bad bind variable.
I searched on google about it but in all cases I got the same answer that user were trying to create trigger with wrong column name. Here is my script.

```
CREATE TABLE  "POPSETTING"     
(   "settingid" number primary key,
    "HOSTNAME" VARCHAR2(50),    
    "INCOMINGSERVER" VARCHAR2(100),
    "REQUIREDSSL" VARCHAR2(1),
    "PORT" NUMBER,
    "OUTGOINGSERVER" VARCHAR2(100),
    "REQUIREDTLS" VARCHAR2(1),
    "REQUIREDAUTH" VARCHAR2(1),
    "PORTTLS" NUMBER,
    "PORTSSL" NUMBER
    )
```

Sequence:

```
create sequence auto_inc start with 1 increment by 1 nomaxvalue
```

Trigger:

```
create or replace trigger popid
   before insert on popsetting
   for each ROW
begin 
   select auto_inc.NEXTVAL
  into :new.settingid from dual 
end;
/
```

Please let me know my mistake.

Comment: also, there's a few missing `;` characters in your trigger

Comment: I think ; is not necessary in oracle XE 10g

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you used the `"` `"` around `settingid` in the create staement you made it case sensitive.
By default oracle refers to column names as upper-case, so there is no `:new.settingid` (which is actually `:new.SETTINGID`)
you may want to try `:new."settingid"` or remove the `""` in the create table statement

Answer (score 0):

For older releases of Oracle, you don't want a trigger just to get a number from a sequence; that causes some overhead.  If you have control over any code that does inserts to the table, just reference the sequence in the insert:

```
insert into POPSETTING
  (SETTING_ID,
   HOSTNAME)
values
  (auto_inc.NEXTVAL, 
  'EXAMPLE.COM');
```

For newer releases of Oracle, you don't have to worry about ensuring programmers reference a sequence for inserts; you can use the identity clause when creating the table and the identity column will get populated automatically:

```
CREATE TABLE "POPSETTING"
  ( settingid number 
        generated always as identity (cache 200) primary key,
   HOSTNAME       VARCHAR2(50),
   INCOMINGSERVER VARCHAR2(100),
   REQUIREDSSL    VARCHAR2(1),
   PORT           NUMBER,
   OUTGOINGSERVER VARCHAR2(100),
   REQUIREDTLS    VARCHAR2(1),
   REQUIREDAUTH   VARCHAR2(1),
   PORTTLS        NUMBER,
   PORTSSL        NUMBER
   );
```

The `CACHE 200` will grab 200 numbers at a time; if you have a table with thousands of inserts a day, then `CACHE 10000` would be fine.